# Является ли определение функции declaration statement?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, объявление

Насколько я знаю [определение](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) - это объявление, которое полностью описывает сущность.
То есть в моём понимании вот это выражение: `int a;` - объявление, а это: `int a = 10;` - определение. Так вот прочитав статью в этом [источнике](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements#:%7E:text=An%20expression%20followed%20by%20a%20semicolon%20is%20a%20statement.&text=Most%20statements%20in%20a%20typical,is%20called%20a%20null%20statement.&text=It%20can%20also%20be%20used,end%20of%20a%20compound%20statement.), я понял что и то и то является `declaration statement`. Пример прямо из статьи:

```
int n = 1; // declaration statement
```

Так вот, исходя из вышесказанного я провел аналогию с функциями. И теперь вопрос, который меня волнует: можно ли определение функции:

```
int foo()
{ return 0; }
```

назвать `declaration statement`? Если нет, то какой термин этому соответствует?

P. S. извиняюсь за принципиальность, но для меня очень важно это понять.

Comment: `int a;` — это тоже определение, если что...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, но как это может быть определением, если не полностью описывает сущность?

Comment: @n1kzzz, и чего именно в `int a;` не хватает для ее полного описания? Если это определение находится вне функции, то начальное значение `a` это 0. Если внутри, то предыдущее (до входа в функцию) состояние стека.

Comment: @n1kzzz, стандарт просто перечисляет, что является определением... самое простое обобщающее определение «определения»: это объявление, которое резервирует память для переменной или содержит тело для функции... в этом винегрете терминов есть ещё и третий ингредиент — *инициализация* — первое присвоение значения переменной, так вот, `int a;` — это «*определение без инициализации*», а `int a=10;` — «*о. с инициализацией*»...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почитал [грамматику](http://eel.is/c++draft/gram).

Это не declaration statement и вообще не statement.

Statement-ы могут находится только в телах функций. Тела состоят из последовательности statement-ов и только из них, поэтому там даже объявления считаются statement-ами.

Снаружи функций объявления являются просто объявлениями.

> Если нет, то какой термин этому соответствует?

Мне кажется никакой. Это просто объявления/определения.

Comment: А почему тогда объявления оканчиваются точкой с запятой? Все стейтменты в языке C++ заканчиваются точкой с запятой - https://ravesli.com/urok-8-struktura-programm-s/. Но объявление снаружи функции не является стейтментом.

Comment: @n1kzzz Сайт врет, не все. Пара фигурных скобок со стейтментами внутри (тела циклов, if-ов, функций, и т.п.) - это сам по себе один большой стейтмент, но точка с запятой после него не ставится. "почему тогда объявления оканчиваются точкой с запятой" Нуу, потому что в грамматике так написано. Стейтменты - не единственная вещь, в конце которой может быть точка с запятой.

Comment: Хм, а если допустим взять конструкцию if (foo()) , foo() здесь это просто вызов функции, стейтментом его назвать нельзя?

Comment: @n1kzzz Да, это не стейтмент. Это выражение. А если написать (на отдельной строке) `foo();`, то `foo();` - это стейтмент (точнее, expression statement), а `foo()` (без `;`) - опять же выражение.

Comment: А как стейтмент отличить от выражения, просто всегда думал, что expression statement и expression это одно и тоже. Можете пожалуйста обозначить между ними грань.

Comment: @n1kzzz Вы бы полистали грамматику. Если вы пишете любое выражение (не в условии if-а или цикла, не в инициализаторе переменой, не в параметре функции, и т.п., а просто само по себе) и ставите после него `;`, то это выражение + `;` вместе являются expression statement-ом.